# Can I use zipimport to ship a embedded python?

Tags: python, delphi, freepascal, embedded-language

Currently, I'm deploying a full python distribution (the original python 2.7 msi) with my app. Which is an embedded web server made with delphi.

[Reading this](http://www.python-forum.org/pythonforum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=18623), I wonder if is possible to embed the necessary python files with my app, to decrease load files and avoid conflict with several python versions.

I have previous experience with [python for delphi](http://mmm-experts.com/Products.aspx?ProductId=3) so I only need to know if only shipping the python dll + zip with the distro + own scripts will work (and if exist any caveats I must know or a sample where I can look)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zipimport` should work just fine for you -- I'm not familiar with Python for Delphi, but I doubt it disables that functionality (an embedding application *can* do that, but it's an unusual choice).  Just remember that what you can zip up and import directly are the Python-coded modules (or just their corresponding `.pyc` or `.pyo` byte codes) -- DLLs (even if renamed as `.pyd`s;-) need to be on disk to be loaded (so if you have a zipfile with them it will need to be unzipped at the start of the app, e.g. into a temporary directory).

Moreover, you don't even need to zip up *all* modules, just those you actually **need** (by transitive closure) -- and you can easily find out exactly which modules those are, with the [modulefinder](http://docs.python.org/library/modulefinder.html) module of the standard Python library.  The example on the documentation page I just pointed to should clarify things.  Happy zipping!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

I'm actually writing automatisation script in Python with the `Zipimport library`. I actually included every `.py` files in my `zip` as well as configuration or xml files needed by those script.

Then, I call a `.command` file targeting a `__main__.py` class that redirect towards the desired script according to my `sys.argv` parameters which is really useful!